# ListView.HasUnevenRows property is not working in Xamarin.Forms.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

If I set "ListView.hasUnevenRows = True", then listview's row height should be based on its item content. This is working in Android and iOS(in almost all the devices).

But in iPhone 12 (14.5), this property is not working which means row height is not set based on the item content.

Has anyone faced this before? I should asked this in Xamarin official forum but before that I just want to confirm whether any workaround is there or I have missed anything here

Comment: When (where) do you set it? Are you setting it In the XAML, or when you construct it, or later? Show the exact code/xaml you are discussing.

Comment: Yes I am setting it in XAML. As a ListView's ItemTemplate, I have added the below label and I am getting the mentioned error,

<Label Text="Hello Guys - Welcome to Xamarin Forms iOS" FontSize="20" 
   Padding="5" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

Comment: I don’t see any previous reports of such a problem. Please simplify the page it is in to the simplest you can, that still has the problem. **Then add the entire page XAML to your question. And the .xaml.cs code-behind file**. (Even better if you create a public repo with the simplest xamarin project you can make that shows the problem. And add a new issue at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues.)

Answer (score 0):

I did a test on my side and it works fine, as you can see below,:

**xmal:**

```
<ListView x:Name="mylist" HasUnevenRows="True">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
  <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </StackLayout>
  </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**codebehind:**

```
 public TestPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<People> peoples = new List<People> {
            new People {Name="111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111222" ,age=10},
            new People{Name="333333333333" ,age=20},
            new People{ Name="hahahahahaha" ,age=30}
        };
        mylist.ItemsSource = peoples;
        
    }
```

[image: result]

and here is a sample link you can test on your side:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/WorkingWithListview/WorkingWithListview/Uneven

Comment: Thanks for the response! In your case issue was not happened but in my case issue is coming. 

Replace your label with the below label code and you will get an issue,

<Label Text="Hello Guys - Welcome to Xamarin Forms iOS" FontSize="20" 
   Padding="5" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

Comment: @Divaker - please download the code that Adrian has kindly supplied. Put in that label that you suspect causes trouble. Report whether the problem happens. (If not, then compare the working project and the not working project. Start changing them, to make them more similar, until you find out exactly what causes it.)

Comment: O find that using ```<ScrollView><StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemSource="{Binding List}"><BindableLayout.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><Label Text={"Binding ."}> //// gives more control over the UI